# If $x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}^+$, then prove that $\frac{x^2}{y} + \frac{y^2}{z} + \frac{z^2}{x}\geq x+y+z$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, cauchy-sequences, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

> If $x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}^+$, then prove that $$\frac{x^2}{y} + \frac{y^2}{z} + \frac{z^2}{x}\geq x+y+z\,.$$

What are other proofs?  Here is my solution.

Note by the AM-GM Inequality that
$$\frac{a^2}{b}+b\geq 2\sqrt{\left(\frac{a^2}{b}\right)\cdot b}=2a$$
for all $a,b>0$.  Therefore,
$$\left(\frac{x^2}{y}+y\right)+\left(\frac{y^2}{z}+z\right)+\left(\frac{z^2}{x}+x\right)\geq 2x+2y+2z\,.$$
This means
$$\left(\frac{x^2}{y}+\frac{y^2}{z}+\frac{z^2}{x}\right)+(x+y+z)\geq 2(x+y+z)\,,$$
which is equivalent to the inequality to be proven.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  Please see "How to Ask a Good Question" at https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question . In particular, unlike some sites, we strongly discourage posts that consist only of a question. You can edit the post to include the source of the problem, its motivation, and what you have attempted.

Answer (score 4):

By C-S $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{x^2}{y}\geq\frac{(x+y+z)^2}{\sum\limits_{cyc}y}=x+y+z.$$
Also, we have
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{x^2}{y}=\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{x^2}{y}-2x+y\right)+x+y+z=\sum_{cyc}\frac{(x-y)^2}{y}+x+y+z\geq x+y+z.$$
The last solution we can write by AM-GM:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{x^2}{y}=\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{x^2}{y}+y\right)-x-y-z\geq\sum_{cyc}2\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{y}\cdot y}-x-y-z=x+y+z.$$
Actually, the following much more stronger inequality is also true.

> Let $x$, $y$ and $z$ be positives such that $x^6+y^6+z^6=3.$ Prove that:
>
> $$\frac{x^2}{y}+\frac{y^2}{z}+\frac{z^2}{x}\geq3.$$