# Is it true that $ \frac{a^2}b+\frac{b^2}c+\frac{c^2}a\geq3$ for positive $a, b, c$ and natural $n$ such that $a^n+b^n+c^n=3$?

Tags: inequality

If $a, b, c > 0$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}^*$, such that $a^n+b^n+c^n=3$ it seems true that
$$
\frac{a^2}{b} + \frac{b^2}{c} + \frac{c^2}{a} \geq 3.
$$

- True if $n = 1$. [See this Math.SE question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3130300/if-x-y-z-in-mathbbr-then-prove-that-fracx2y-fracy2z-f?noredirect=1)
- True if $n = 4$. [See this AoPS post.](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2445270p20292824)
- Perhaps true for $n = 6$. [See this AoPS post.](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1832956p12278873%22)

Have a counterexample if it is false for some $n$.

Comment: By checking with python $a,b,c,n=61,57,96,9$ is a counterexample

Comment: @Marco  I believe the correct question is, if $a^n+b^n+c^n=3$, then $\frac{a^2}{b} + \frac{b^2}{c} + \frac{c^2}{a} \geq 3$

Comment: It's false for $n>7$ even if $a^n+b^n+c^n=3$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let
$$a=1,b=\sqrt[8]{\frac{1}{2}}, c=\sqrt[8]{2-\frac{1}{2}}$$

Than $a^8+b^8+c^8=3$ and
$$
\frac{a^2}{b}+\frac{b^2}{c}+\frac{c^2}{a}\approx 2.9965288195820197
$$
As shown [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=where+is+Power%5B2%2C%5C%2840%29Divide%5B1%2Cx%5D%5C%2841%29%5D%2BPower%5B%5C%2840%29Divide%5B1%2C%5C%2840%294%5C%2840%29Divide%5B3%2C2%5D%5C%2841%29%5C%2841%29%5D%5C%2841%29%2C%5C%2840%29Divide%5B1%2Cx%5D%5C%2841%29%5D%2BPower%5B%5C%2840%29Divide%5B3%2C2%5D%5C%2841%29%2C%5C%2840%29Divide%5B2%2Cx%5D%5C%2841%29%5D%3C3) the inequality
$$
\frac{a^2}{b}+\frac{b^2}{c}+\frac{c^2}{a}=2^{\frac{1}{x}}+6^{\frac{1}{x}}+\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{\frac{2}{x}}<3
$$
is always true for $x>7$. So
$$
a=1, b=2^{-\frac{1}{n}}, c=\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}
$$
are a counterexample for any $n \ge 8$

For $n=7$ we can choose
$$
a=1, b=\sqrt[7]{\frac{3}{4}}, c=\sqrt[7]{\frac{5}{4}}
$$
and we have
$$
\frac{a^2}{b}+\frac{b^2}{c}+\frac{c^2}{a}\approx 2.9999784302204775
$$
(similarly as above this leads to a counterexample for $n \ge 7$, see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=where+is++%284%2F3%29%5E%281%2Fx%29%2B%28%283%2F4%29%5E%282%2Fx%29%29%2F%28%285%2F4%29%5E%281%2Fx%29%29%2B%285%2F4%29%5E%282%2Fx%29%3C3) )

Comment: thank you so much